# 'this' behaviour in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, this

I have this simple script:

```
console.log(this);

var speak = function(what) {
    console.log(what);
    console.log(this);  
};

speak('ciao!');
```

If I load an html page that reference this script, in the browser's console I see this

```
Window {speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis, caches: CacheStorage, localStorage: Storage, sessionStorage: Storage, webkitStorageInfo: DeprecatedStorageInfo…}

temp2.js:112 ciao!

temp2.js:113 undefined
```

My understanding is that 'this' is the bind to the ' window global' object (at least in the context of my sample), so I would expect to see 'this' valued to 'window' even within the function.
I don't understand what's wrong when I execute my program.
If write my code in the browser repl, then everything works as expected (both console.log(this) return the window object

Can anybody explain me what I am missing here?

Cheers, Giovanni

Comment: Does `temp2.js`, or whichever file contains your code, have `"use strict";` at the top? What you see is what you get when `speak` is in strict mode.

Comment: So what environment/mode are you running that code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside "normal" function calls, `this` is `undefined` if the function is [**strict**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). A function is strict if it contains the `"use strict";` directive or if was defined in a strict environment.

So it seems that your code is evaluated in a global, *strict* environment (because `console.log(this)` outside the function still logs the global object).

Comment: Thanks Felix, that was the case. 'use strict' was at the very top of my script. I am following a course and there are many commented lines between line 1 (strict) and my code, so overlooked that. Would you recommend to use 'use strict' every time?

Comment: Yes, strict mode enforces some "saner" rules. See the MDN article for more details about what it enables.